# Value Change Within a .xml file not Resulting in a Change within Civ 5 Game

Tags: civilization-5, mods, macos

I changed the value of the research speed in the Civ5GameSpeeds.xml file on mac, but when I run the game, researching costs are still at the default values. I tried restarting the game and my computer but nothing happens. I know I have permission to read & write the file too. Also I changed the values within the CIV5GameOptions.xml file to see more options successfully, but I don't know why it's not working for the CIV5GameSpeeds.xml

Here is a snippet of code

> ```
>   <Row>
>         <Type>GAMESPEED_QUICK</Type>
>         <Description>TXT_KEY_GAMESPEED_QUICK</Description>
>         <Help>TXT_KEY_GAMESPEED_QUICK_HELP</Help>
>         <DealDuration>25</DealDuration>
>         <GrowthPercent>67</GrowthPercent>
>         <TrainPercent>67</TrainPercent>
>         <ConstructPercent>67</ConstructPercent>
>         <CreatePercent>67</CreatePercent>
>         <ResearchPercent>200</ResearchPercent> <!-- User changed original value of 67 to 200 -->
>         <GoldPercent>67</GoldPercent>
>         <GoldGiftMod>125</GoldGiftMod>
>         <BuildPercent>67</BuildPercent>
>         <ImprovementPercent>67</ImprovementPercent>
>         <GreatPeoplePercent>67</GreatPeoplePercent>
>         <CulturePercent>67</CulturePercent>
>         <BarbPercent>67</BarbPercent>
>         <FeatureProductionPercent>67</FeatureProductionPercent>
>         <UnitDiscoverPercent>67</UnitDiscoverPercent>
>         <UnitHurryPercent>67</UnitHurryPercent>
>         <UnitTradePercent>67</UnitTradePercent>
>         <GoldenAgePercent>80</GoldenAgePercent>
>         <HurryPercent>100</HurryPercent>
>         <InflationPercent>45</InflationPercent>
>         <InflationOffset>-60</InflationOffset>
>         <VictoryDelayPercent>67</VictoryDelayPercent>
>         <IconAtlas>GAMESPEED_ATLAS</IconAtlas>
>         <PortraitIndex>3</PortraitIndex>
>     </Row>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be changing the wrong file.

As far as I can understand, when civ loads its data it first loads all the data in the "Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets" folder apart from the "DLC" folder. It then goes into the "DLC" folder and loads those in a specific order (Brave New World after Gods and Kings) overwriting the old data each time it finds a duplicate file. 
It then does the same for the "MODS" folder in your documents folder.

To change game data you therefore need to change it in the last place the game loads, which for game speeds means the latest major DLC you play with or any mods that change it.